# Continuous fraction approximation of pi

Tags: matlab

While studying for Matlab, I came up with this problem: given an integer `1<d<15` find the smallest `p,q` (positive integers) such that `abs(p/q-pi)<=10^-d`.

So here's my attempt: I first thought that I need to bound `p,q` in order to create loops, so I put as input data some `M,N`upper bounds for `p,q` respectively. So here is my algorithm:

```
       M=input('Give an upper bound for p:')
       N=input('Give an upper bound for q:')
       d=input('Give a positive integer between 1 and 15:')

       for q=1:N
       for p=1:M
       if abs(pi-p/q)<=10^(-d)
       break
       end
       end
       end
```

What is wrong about it?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code seems OK: are you experiencing any particular issues? Of course, if M and N get large enough, it will take forever…

Comment: It doesn't work.. I will always get pmin=M and qmin=N as an answer, if I complete fprintf details.

Comment: That might happen because the ```for``` loops always end before you hit the (p,q) pair that satisfies the condition. What values of M, N and d are you using?

Comment: Yes, that's what I figured. But how do I fix it ? (I've used way too several combinations of p,q for a fixed d)

Comment: Just to be clear: when I said the code looks OK I meant that I couldn't spot any syntax error. I don't know whether your approach is suitable for the task of finding p and q, and I don't even know whether that inequality has a solution, to be honest.

Comment: well for M,N>22 and d=1, there is always the approximation 22/7~=3.1428

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the the way you chose to terminate the `for` loops: `break` only stops the inner loop. Try this code instead, and check the value of `p` and `q` at which the execution stops:

```
 M=input('Give an upper bound for p:')
 N=input('Give an upper bound for q:')
 d=input('Give a positive integer between 1 and 15:')

 for q=1:N
 for p=1:M
   if abs(pi-p/q)<=10^(-d)
     [p,q]
     error('Found!') % Arrest the program when condition is met
 end
 end
 end
```

which gives the following output:

[image]

Of course, there are better ways of capturing all the possible pairs of integers that meet the condition (e.g. by using `disp` instead of `error`). That goes beyond the scope of this answer, but I shall provide a couple of examples here:

```
clear; clc;

M=input('Give an upper bound for p:')
N=input('Give an upper bound for q:')
d=input('Give a positive integer between 1 and 15:')

pairs = []; % p,q pairs are stored here
k = 1; % counter

for q=1:N
    for p=1:M
        if abs(pi-p/q)<=10^(-d)
            pairs(k,1) = p; 
            pairs(k,2) = q;
            k = k + 1; % increment the counter
        end
    end
end
```

The script above will end quietly: the (p,q) pairs will be stored in the `pair` matrix.

The following one will print directly the pairs:

```
clear; clc;

M=input('Give an upper bound for p:')
N=input('Give an upper bound for q:')
d=input('Give a positive integer between 1 and 15:')

for q=1:N
    for p=1:M
        if abs(pi-p/q)<=10^(-d)
            out = sprintf("(%d, %d)", p,q);
            disp(out);
        end
    end
end
```

For the sake of the experiment, and following up on @Cris Luengo's comment, here's a slightly more elaborate version of the script: the `for` loops are encapsulated in a dedicated function and a `while` loop keeps good track of the progress and populates the `res` matrix with the `(p,q)` pairs:

```
clear; clc;

M=input('Give an upper bound for p:');
N=input('Give an upper bound for q:');
d=input('Give a positive integer between 1 and 15:');

close_to_pi = @(px,qx) abs(pi-px/qx)<=10^(-d); % returns true/false

p = 1; q = 1;
count = 0;

res = nan(N*M,2) ; % (p,q) pairs are stored here; preallocate for speed!

tic % starts the timer
while (q <= N)
    [p,q, found] = approx_pi(p, q, N, M, close_to_pi);
    
    if found
        count = count + 1;
        res(count,:) = [p,q]; % populates output var

    end
    
    if p<M % we aren't done with p
        p = p + 1;
    else % reset p and increment q
        p = 1;
        q = q + 1;
    end

    
end
res(isnan(res(:,1)),:) = []; % gets rid of the empty elements
disp(count)
toc % stops the timer and prints elapsed time


function [p, q, found] = approx_pi(p0, q0, N, M, fun)

for q=q0:N
    for p=p0:M
        if fun(p,q)
            found = 1;
            return
        end % if
    end % for p
    p0 = 1;
end % for q

found = 0;

end % approx_pi
```

If you are interested in continuous fraction approximations of `pi`, try `rat(pi, Tol)` where `Tol` is the tolerance. Further details [here](https://it.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rat.html).

Comment: It doesn't work.. It just appears that there is error on line 10 etc...

Comment: What does the error say? My code is triggering an error intentionally to stop the for loops when the condition is met... Have you checked the values of p and q after the program has stopped? Just run my code first: it only works as a script. If you put it in a function, p and q will go out of scope once the program stops...

Comment: I updated the answer so that it prints p and q before quitting. You have to consider that as soon as ```error``` is called, the program stops and exits. Any command you put after that will be ignored.

Comment: Yes, now it works thank you. But do you think is there any other way without using "[p,q]", error?? To the point I'm studying my book and where this problem is placed, these have not been mentioned.

Comment: Sure, I am posting a possible, nicer, solution. :) Please, consider upvoting/accepting my answer :)

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately these are still out of my studying tools yet. But I really appreciate your help. Unfortunately, I don't have enough reputation yet. I just joined the forum.

Comment: The nicest way to break out of multiple loops is to put them in a function and `return`. This has become easier with the ability to write functions at the end of a script file. Still, I like the versions where you print all solutions, there’s no reason to stop after the first one.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I've included a version of the script that encapsulates the ```for``` loops into a function.  Turns out that keeping track of the indexes requires some attention, but overall the solution is almost as fast (or slow, depending on the point of view!) as the others.